# Can't insert a file into MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, file-upload, mongodb-query, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4, and I'm trying to save a file (.jpg, .pdf, etc...) in my MongoDB, my file isn't higher than 16MB so I don't need gridFS but still can't save my file, my HTML form is this:

```
<form method="POST" action="file" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nuevo Archivo</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

and my controller is like this:

```
public function storefile(Request $request)
{
    $m = new archivo;
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $db = $m->pruebaerp; 
    $collection = $db->archivos;
    $collection->save($file);

    return view('/informacion_entidad');
}
```

Comment: So what happens? Errors? Invalid data? And what's the reason for saving the files in mongo to start with?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when I want to insert the file it gives me "Trying to get property of non-object" and I don't know what else I can do, I'm new in all of MongoDB and Laravel stuff

Comment: Where is that error thrown? What line? You need to let us know what and where the issue is.